# Should the calves be tense when standing still?

Tags: posture

I'm becoming more sensitive to my balance and trying to feel an equal weight on both feet while squatting and hip hinging. I've noticed that in the very basic standing position, my left calf (gastrocnemius, higher up) is activated and pushing my toes against the floor, while my right calf is pretty quiet. Going on one leg for skater squats, it's kind of the same way, and in biking, my calf helps flex my knee on the left side but stays quiet on the right. Does a normal standing posture involve calf tension or is it mainly in the muscles of the thigh?